# Using custom DLL with Lua 5.1

Tags: dll, lua

I'm trying to use a custom DLL from within Lua. I have a simple DLL, for example, like

```
extern "C"
{
  static int function_1(lua_State* L)
  {
    std::cout << "[DLL]this is a custom function" << std::endl;
    lua_pushnumber(L, 10);
    return 1;
  }

  __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl luaopen_myDLL(lua_State* L)
  { 
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    std::cout << "[DLL] being initialized!" << std::endl;

    lua_register(L, "fun1", function_1);
    luaL_dofile(L, "./run.lua");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

written in VS and built as dll.

After running within Lua

```
package.loadlib("./myDLL.dll", "luaopen_myDLL")()
```

or

```
require("myDLL")
```

the DLL is loaded and runs like expected and also runs the specified run.lua that execute function_1 just fine.

The run.lua has nothing special in it, just something like

```
f = function_1()
print("[Lua] Function_1 says", f, "\n");
```

My current issues now are:

1. I cannot run function_1() from the initial Lua script calling the DLL. Trying to do that I get

   `attempt to call global 'function_1' (a nil value)`
2. i must use `L = luaL_newstate();` inside my C code. For some reason, it doesn't work with the passed lua_State*, which I think is the reason why I cannot call the registered functions from the LUA script loading my DLL. Before running luaL_newstate() my lua_State has a valid address which doesn't change after the newstate.

I could theoretically run any Lua script from within my C library executing the registered functions, but this seems more like a dirty workaround to me.

My question now is if I'm missing something essential?

p.s.: I'm using Lua 5.1

Comment: Any Lua script will see your function as `fun1` instead of `function_1`.

Comment: You should use passed `lua_State*` instead of creating new one with `luaL_newstate`.  What error are you getting when using passed Lua state?

Comment: I used fun1() of course. Sorry i wrote that wrong in the question. ( As mentioned, fun1() works when i use it inside a lua script called by the C method with luaL_dofile(L, "run.lua"); )  When I try to execute my C code without a newstate i get a "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)", as soon i reach a part where i try to use the passed state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should work. It **may not** work because of the following reasons:

- your binary you use to run initial Lua script (that has `require("myDLL")` in it) has a different Lua version and/or does not use shared dll.
- your Lua headers you use in your C++ code have different Lua version from original `lua.exe`
- you link your project against different Lua version
- you compile Lua again with your solution (you must use **only** headers and already provided .lib file with Lua distribution, if you want to use `lua.exe`)

To make your code available in Lua you must use Lua headers for proper Lua version and link against proper .lib file and use lua.exe that uses shared library (lua.dll, I guess).

```
static int function_1(lua_State* L)
{
    std::cout << "[DLL]this is a custom function" << std::endl;
    lua_pushnumber(L, 10);
    return 1;
}

extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) luaopen_quik(lua_State *L) {
    std::cout << "[DLL] being initialized!" << std::endl;
    lua_register(L, "fun1", function_1);
    luaL_dofile(L, "./run.lua");
    return 0;
}
```

P. S. please provide your solution files so I can help further because it is not an issue with the code. -- it's the linkage issue.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I indeed linked to a different LUA in my VS solution creating my DLL. Thanks a lot.